# Where does statistical physics/mechanics fit in with QFT and GR?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, statistical-mechanics

We have two theories namely,Quantum Field Theory which works very well at sub-atomic scales, and the General Relativity which works very well at very large scales.So, my question is where does statistical physics/mechanics fit in? What role statistical physics/mechanics play in today's modern physics? Did it play any role in the development of QFT or GR?

And concepts like Renormalization group and regularization were discovered in the literature of statistical physics/mechanics?

Comment: Hi Gary, it's a very interesting question, as I have started studying statistical mechanics myself recently, and I did not realize how many areas it's involved in, but for that reason, I think your question is way too broad for any one answer. Maybe consider taking it one topic at a time.

Comment: As a matter of historical accuracy the RG was introduced in the context of particle physics and only later extended to statistical physics. Good question anyway +1.

Comment: The Boltzmann distribution has been adapted to GR, of note. A description of it is in Straumann.